# Call to undefined function crack_opendict()

Tags: php

I am getting below error, not understanding what php library should install. Could anyone please tell me how to fix below error:

```
Call to undefined function crack_opendict()
```

Already searched in google for this, but not finding any perfect solution at all.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are calling `crack_opendict()` Try searching for this function in your code. Since this function is not defined PHP returns an error.

Comment: @Corne But I found this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crack-opendict.php

Comment: if you have php errors enabled, it should tell you what line & file the call is occurring in.  ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`crack_opendict()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.crack-opendict.php):

> PECL crack >= 0.1

See [Installation of PECL extensions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php) for more information on installing such extensions.